# How to access a view when adding multiple merge layouts in the same ViewGroup?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a GridLayout to show players data in a ListView Activity (In a future I probably change to a really ListView, but for the purpose of this question think that is mandatory to be a GridLayout).

In an activity result I have to add new rows to the layout and as all rows have the same components, I put all row components in a new layout file with a merge parent and when need to add a row simply inflate with the GridLayout as rootView and attach to true.

The problem is when I add a new row as the components id are the same, all the time I change the properties (text of a TextView) of the first row.

How can I access the other views with the same id?

Comment: the IDs must be unique if you wanna find a view with it later.

Comment: @Alécio So no way to use a merge layout twice under the same ViewGroup?

Comment: Yes you can, but if you want that the findViewById works the way you want, you have to do it on the ViewGroup of the merged layout, not on the Root view. The ID has to be unique within the viewgroup you're calling the findViewById.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have search many times and the only thing that I found is that **You can't do it**.

So I have to get alternatives like:

- Add then directly in the code. So you mess code and UI.
- Change `<merge>` element to other. So it's inefficient.
- Use the index to get the view instead of the ID. Again you mess code and UI, but a little less than with first option.

In my case I have used the index letting me with code like:

```
inflater.inflate(R.layout.player_in_match, llPlayers, true);

// 4 Is because I have 4 elements in the R.layout.player_in_match
// and I wanna get the first of them.
TextView tvName = (TextView) llPlayers.getChildAt(llPlayers.getChildCount() - 4);

tvName.setText(name);
```